# set transperent background for constraint layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

hi I have to make a view like the below image .

[image]

But when i make the parent view transperent , default background is showing like this:

[image]

a transperent view is showing behind the main view.

my xml starts like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shadow"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressLayout_frame"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bgCircle"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                >

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTimeCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="29sp"
                    app:customTypeFace="roboto_light" />
```

how can I hide the view behind . why does this layout come ? any suggestions would be helpful . thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **To remove default background of the dialog...**

[image]

Step 1:

- Create a *custom_dialog.xml*

  ```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_20sdp"
   android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_25sdp"
   android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_25sdp" >

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/left_vertical_gl"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02" />
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/right_vertical_gl"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />


   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/center_horizontal_gl"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.48" />

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/top_horizontal_gl"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.044" />


   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
       android:id="@+id/end_horizontal_gl"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView9"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:fontFamily="@font/segui_black"
       android:text="Are You Sure?"
       android:textColor="#484A67"
       android:textSize="@dimen/_24ssp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_horizontal_gl" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView10"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/segoe"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Are you sure you want to sign out?"
       android:textColor="#484A67"
       android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_vertical_gl"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/yesTv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/segui_semi_bold"
       android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
       android:text="Yes"
       android:textColor="#AD7BFF"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_vertical_gl"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/noTv"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/segoe"
       android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
       android:text="No"
       android:textColor="#6D6E85"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/yesTv"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yesTv"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/yesTv"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="143dp" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  ```

Step 2:

- ***Go to your dialog activity***
- Add the below line to your dialog code

> popUpDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

**Complete code of the dialog**

```
private lateinit var popUpDialog: Dialog
 private fun buyLifeLineDialog() {
        popUpDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_buy_lifelines)
        popUpDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        val yesTv = popUpDialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.yesTv);
        val noTv = popUpDialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.noTv);
        popUpDialog.show()
        yesTv.setOnClickListener {
            if (isCheatLl) {
                mViewModel.buyCheatLifeline(index,lifeLinesPackagesModel)
            }
            else{
                mViewModel.buyRespawnLifeline(index,lifeLinesPackagesModel)
            }
            popUpDialog.dismiss()
        }
        noTv.setOnClickListener {
            popUpDialog.dismiss()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how do you display this window in your app , but I suppose that you display it as custom dialog , so the problem is that you need to add a transparent theme for your dialog to get the same design or your dialog will fill the transparent spaces with this black color or white depends on your app theme , so to solve this problem you need to add this style in your theme.xml file or style.xml

```
 <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and then you create a new custom dialog in your activity like this

```
//Here i will create new dialog with a custom style which I added in Theme.xml
final AlertDialog dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialogCustom).create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
//Here I added my xml file , you can replace test with your own xml file
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
        dialog2.setView(convertView);
        dialog2.setCancelable(false);
    //Here we tell the dialog to display , you can call show() when click a button
        dialog2.show();
```

and here it's my simple design to get a transparent background

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl2"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressLayout_frame"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bgCircle"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/pers_icon"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true">


            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="218dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="129dp" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now this is the final result , you can make your own design
[image]

Comment: thanku very much for your time , and u gave the proper suggestion . "popUpDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)) " solved my issue :)